# What is "Do you haz teh codez"?

Tags: discussion, support, advertising

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Do you haz teh codez?" is an intentionally misspelled, poor grammar, version of the question: "Do you have the [source] code?".  It is written in the style of an Internet meme called [*lolcatz*](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/lolcats).  In this particular case, the phrase is meant to be considered humorous.  Origins of "teh codez" version of this meme may be a direct result of [this TDWTF article](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx).

Similar phrasing can also be associated with a mocking, or disapproving, tone when directed at [inadequate] requests for assistance from inexperienced users.  See also: [*n00b*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=noob).

Comment: +1 for the n00b article :)

Comment: +1 for the wikipedia tone.

Comment: Also explained on http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13231/what-does-do-you-haz-teh-codez-mean

Answer (score 8):

It's sort of a meme about asking programmers to do your work for you. In retrospect it seems odd to have made it into an ad.